# How to paste transparent image into flash project

Tags: flash, transparency, photoshop, copy-paste

I've created a short text (a word) in photoshop with the blending options I prefer and now it's all done I would like to paste it into my flash project.
The problem is I can't get the text to be transparent in the flash, I always see the white background which is not very nice since the background on which the text will show is actually a picture.
How to make this text transparent? In photoshop I started a new transparent project. Copying from a .GIF file also doesn't work...
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to

1. Save it as a transparent **PNG 24** using Photoshop: File > Save for Web & Devices
2. Then import that image into Flash

PNG format will maintain colors and transparency perfectly.

Comment: works like a charm, still think the text could be of better quality someway. I know our previous text was actually built of out of several colored or black shapes/lines (not flash shapes, but actual drawn shapes) and when layered over each other in the right order they displayed a letter/text with the desired 'effects'

Answer (score 0):

I you use CS4 you can import the psd directly, and you will see plenty of choices on how to deal with each photoshop layer.

The importer will preserve the layer transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Check this also. You have to import the text image to Flash.

1. convert that into movieclip by pressing f8
2. then click that image, check Properties (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd>), where you find Color effects,

In that Style--> alpha and reduce to 20.

So your image looks like transparent obj. Try this.